# Angular Material UI errors after upgrading from 11 to 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to update my angular application from angular 11 to 12 with angular-material and getting some errors,

Error No.1

```
- error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-select'.
1. If 'mat-select' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-select' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

2697         <mat-select placeholder="Vorgesetzter" style="width: 60%; margin-bottom:10px" [(ngModel)]="vorgesetzter">
                                                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Error No.2

````
```- error NG8001: 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2     <mat-toolbar role="toolbar" class="task-header mt_toolbar">
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
````

Error No.3

```
 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2691         <mat-icon style="color: black;">close</mat-icon>
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Error No.4

```
- error NG8001: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2230       <mat-form-field class="mb-1" style="width: 100%;height: 60px;">
```

Error No.5

```
- Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: $map: #2813e4 is not a map.
   ╷
43 │     default: map.get($base-palette, $default),
   │              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_theming.scss 43:14             define-palette()
  node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_theming-deprecated.scss 16:11  palette()
  src/assets/styles/scss/_material.variables.scss 7:11                        @import
  src/assets/styles/app.scss 1:9                                              root stylesheet
    at processResult (/Users/muzafarali/Sites/angular/a11-erbium/Frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:701:19)
    at /Users/muzafarali/Sites/angular/a11-erbium/Frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:807:5
    at /Users/muzafarali/Sites/angular/a11-erbium/Frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at /Users/muzafarali/Sites/angular/a11-erbium/Frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (/Users/muzafarali/Sites/angular/a11-erbium/Frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.callback (/Users/muzafarali/Sites/angular/a11-erbium/Frontend/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:54:7)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (/Users/muzafarali/Sites/angular/a11-erbium/Frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/sass/sass-service.js:134:25)
    at Worker.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (internal/worker.js:201:53)
    at MessagePort.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at MessagePort.onmessage (internal/worker/io.js:80:8)
    at MessagePort.exports.emitMessage (internal/per_context/messageport.js:11:10)
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "now-build": "ng build --prod --output-path dist",
    "prod-aot": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --common-chunk",
    "prod": "ng build --prod --aot false --build-optimizer false",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk-experimental": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/material-experimental": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "12.0.5",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^5.1.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^5.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@shtian/ng-pick-datetime": "^11.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",
    "@techiediaries/ngx-qrcode": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.26",
    "angular-highcharts": "^12.0.0",
    "angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^3.0.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "3.2.1",
    "d3": "5.12.0",
    "date-fns": "1.30.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.5",
    "dragula": "3.7.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^7.2.1",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "leaflet": "1.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-material-multilevel-menu": "^5.5.3",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ngx-currency": "^2.5.2",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material-dayjs": "^4.0.7",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.20",
    "ngx-logger": "^4.2.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "8.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^13.4.0",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.5",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "sass": "^1.35.1",
    "screenfull": "5.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.5",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.15",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.29.1"
  }
}
```

and tsconfig.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/erbium",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
}
```

i have import all material modules inside app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
// import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DeviceDetectorModule } from 'ngx-device-detector';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';

// import Toaster module for ui
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';


import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';

import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox'
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon'
import {MatCardModule, MatCardContent} from '@angular/material/card'
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle'
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list'
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list'
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu'
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav'
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar'
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select'
import {MatOptionModule, MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core'
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar'
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle'
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'
import { MatTab, MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs'
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';


import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

// import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { NGXLogger, LoggerModule, NgxLoggerLevel } from "ngx-logger";



import { AppRoutes } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Common Module
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { Config } from './config/config';
import { LocalStorage } from './libs/localstorage';
import { AuthGuard } from './authentication/auth-guard.service';
import { SearchPipe } from './search.pipe';
import { LoaderModule } from './loader/loader.module';
import { LoaderService } from './loader/loader.service';
import { LoaderInterceptorService } from './services/interceptor.service';
    

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

// const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
//   suppressScrollX: true
// };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {
      useHash: true, anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
      relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'
    }),
    HttpClientModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    FormsModule,
    DeviceDetectorModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    LoggerModule.forRoot({ serverLoggingUrl: '/v1/logs', level: NgxLoggerLevel.DEBUG, serverLogLevel: NgxLoggerLevel.ERROR }),
    // MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    LoaderModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule
  ],
  providers: [
    LocalStorage,
    Config,
    AuthGuard,
    SharedService,
    LoaderService,
    RequestService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: LoaderInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    },
  ],
  exports: [
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

anything else required to sort out please reply

Comment: Please don't tag spam; [angularjs] is for [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), an older framework that is pretty much stuck at its current version (<2). [angular] is for [Angular](https://angular.io) the one that is currently at version 12.

Answer (score 0):

rebuild `package.json` and `yarn.lock`
generate new angular project and  copy the `package.json` and `yarn.lock` into your existing projects. It works for me

I referred below link to fix my error

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20967